# Struts2 Form Submit error

Tags: struts2, struts

When i call an action through form i am getting the following error.

```
No result defined for action com.______.actions.UserAction and result input
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:375)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
```

I am getting this error in `invocation.invoke()`

If i hit the action through URL it is working fine.

Please help...

Here's the relevant struts.xml fragment:

```
<action name="*Link" method="{1}" class="com.______.actions.UserAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="loggingStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <result name="userInfo" type="tiles">userInfo</result>
    <result name="sessionout" type="tiles">sessionOut</result>
</action>
```

if i remove  `<interceptor-ref name="loggingStack"></interceptor-ref>` it work's fine.

Comment: What's `loggingStack` look like? Looks like there's either a conversion or validation error and it's trying to go to the default result, "input".

Comment: what's the definition of `loggingStack`?

Comment: Did you try replacing "<interceptor-ref name="loggingStack"></interceptor-ref>" with "<interceptor-ref name="loggingStack"/>"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above issue has been solved?

In my action class i was using `ArrayList<Integer>` where as my form submiting String.

I changed `ArrayList<Integer>` `to ArrayList<String>`